# How to get rid off "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model in Ado.Net EF.
I have a one to many relation and when I want to Add the entities I get the error

"An entity object cannot be referenceed by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Any clue?

Something similar to

```
Template template = new Template();
...
...
while (from < to)
{
    Course course = new Course();
    .....
    template.Course.Add(course);
    .....
}
courseEntities.AddToTemplate(template); // Problem line
courseEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was getting this message until i started to store the data context in the [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(VS.80).aspx) Property. This means you can use the same data context for the current web request. That way you don't end up with 2 data contexts referencing the same entities.

Here is a good post on [DataContext Life Management](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx).

I hope it helps.

Dave

Answer (score 2):

"template", or something that it references, has already been added to courseEntities *or* another context. I don't see anything in the code you show it would do that, but it is certainly happening. Perhaps it's happening in some of the code that you've trimmed. Look at the EntityState property of "template" in the debugger, and look at the EntityState of the properties of "template" as well. This should help you find out which entity instance is already in a context.

Comment: *"template, **or something that it references**"* - Thank you Craig, that just solved *another* EF issue for me (that's, what, 10 EF issues you've helped me with now?).  This error occurs not only if the entity is attached to another context, but if *any* object referenced by this entity is attached to another context!

Answer (score 1):

I already realize the problem. I have another relation and I get the other entity from another context.

Answer (score 1):

Let me relate my experience with this nasty error and point out the terrain chasing it will take you over leading to a tremendously simple solution.

CompanyGroup is pretty simple. It has a name and it has a Company object.

I started with this:

```
1        public static void Add(CompanyGroup item)
2        {
3            try
4            {
5                using (Entities scope = new Entities())
6                {
7             scope.AddToCompanyGroup(item);
8                       scope.SaveChanges();
9                }
10            }
11            catch (Exception ex)
12            {
13                LogException(ex, item);
14                throw;
15            }     
16  }
```

And got this error:

> {"An entity object cannot be
>   referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker."}

So, I added this between lines 6 and 7:

```
        (IEntityWithChangeTracker)item).SetChangeTracker(null);
```

That rewarded me with:

> {"The object cannot be added to the
>   ObjectStateManager because it already
>   has an EntityKey. Use
>   ObjectContext.Attach to attach an
>   object that has an existing key."}

So I changed

```
scope.AddToCompanyGroup(item);
```

to

```
scope.Attach(item);
```

Now it complained about:

> {"An object with a temporary EntityKey
>   value cannot be attached to an object
>   context."}

(beginning to sound like some of the girls I dated in my youth -- never content -- but I digress)

So I made the entity key null (didn't work) and used the method to create new (didn't work, either)

Along the way, I got this error, too:

> {"The source query for this
>   EntityCollection or EntityReference
>   cannot be returned when the related
>   object is in either an  added state or
>   a detached state and was not
>   originally retrieved using the
>   NoTracking merge option."}

The Solution?

Replace the core, lines 7 and 8, with:

```
                CompanyGroup newcg = new CompanyGroup();
                newcg.GroupName = item.GroupName;
                newcg.Company = scope.Company.Where(c => c.CompanyID == item.Company.CompanyID).First();

      scope.AddToCompanyGroup(newcg);
                scope.SaveChanges();
```

Essentially, I took the data passed via 'item', and moved it to newly created object of the same type that introduces the same 
scope as the one used in the Add.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the simplest and correct solution. You need one db context per httprequest.

EF4 Code First template Global.asax.cs 
http://gist.github.com/574505

```
void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 HttpContext.Current.Items[SessionKey] = new Db();
}

void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 var disposable = HttpContext.Current.Items[SessionKey] as IDisposable;
 if (disposable != null)
  disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem I was solved by removing from the object that I update, extra relationships with other entities (Virtual). Left only their ID.

This is wrong code

```
dataFileEntity.IterParameterValue = parameterValueEntity.ParameterValue;
dataFileEntity.IterParameterValueId = parameterValueEntity.ParameterValue.Id;
dataFileEntity.ResultParameter = parameterValueEntity.ResultParameter;
dataFileEntity.ResultParameterId = parameterValueEntity.ResultParameter.Id;
dataFileEntity.RawDataResult = result.Value;
```

This is right

```
dataFileEntity.IterParameterValueId = parameterValueEntity.ParameterValue.Id;
dataFileEntity.ResultParameterId = parameterValueEntity.ResultParameter.Id;
dataFileEntity.RawDataResult = result.Value;
RequestTestRawDataFileRepository.AddOrUpdate(dataFileEntity);
```

Я эту проблему решила, убрав из объекта, который я апдейтила лишние связи с другими сущностями (Virtual). Оставила только их  id.

Comment: Automatic translator tells me the last paragraph reads 'I have this problem solved, removing from the object that I update is unnecessary due to other entities (Virtual). Leaving only their id.'

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize your Entities only one time.

Like as

If You more than one time initialize your Entities.

You will get the error:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

ex:

```
public class Test

{

 private Entities db=new Entities();

 public static void Add(CompanyGroup item)
    {
        try
        {

         db.CompanyGroup.Add(item);
         db.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }     
    }   
}
```