# NopCommerce EF problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nopcommerce

I am using nopcommerce for my web shop and I am using Tasks that are getting information from an external system when an order has been shipped. When it is shipped I want to capture the payment and then set it as shipped. However, I keep getting EF errors. Any way to get around this for now? I need to have it up and running

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

See my code below:

```
                int orderId = PBSManager.GetOrderIdByCustomOrderNumber(customOrderNumber);
            NopObjectContext db = ObjectContextHelper.CurrentObjectContext;
            Order order = db.Orders.SingleOrDefault(c => c.OrderId == orderId);
            //Incorrect order id    
            if (order == null)
            {
                //Skip this one if we cannot find the id
                continue;
            }
            if (OrderManager.CanCapture(order))
            {
                string error = string.Empty;
                OrderManager.Capture(order, ref error);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    PBSManager.HandleCaptureError(order, error);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (OrderManager.CanShip(order))
            {
                OrderManager.Ship(order.OrderId, true);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing that probably you are creating another context in the OrderManager class. You should use the same context.

Can this link be of any help

[Multiple instances of context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620084/how-to-get-rid-off-an-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-o)

Comment: Yeah, I know. The problem is that it is nop's own context manager that causes the issues

Comment: So if their context is still around, grab and reuse it....  ...or clone the entity object

Comment: I think, I can't help much, but an excerpt from the following article says that, GetEntityById should not be used. Any chances that you may be using this inside the PBSManager class.  http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/6677/custom-task-and-entity-framework-exception.aspx

Comment: But the only way to grab their contet is using "ObjectContextHelper.CurrentObjectContext", which causes this error. And Hps, I am not using GetEntityById. I read all those posts at nopcommerce, they all seem to have the same issue but no solution

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't nopCommerce store the current context in the HttpContext, have you tried looking for it in there?

Comment: There is no context in the httpcontext, that's the problem

Comment: right sorry about that, have you tried grabbing some plugins or other code that also use Tasks to see how they handle this type of situation?