# asp.mvc3 deleting an object from db

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

Here is my code:

```
 public ActionResult DeleteItem(int id)
        {
            using (var cont = new PhotoGalleryDBEntities4())
            {
                var refToDel = cont.Referanslars.First(x => x.Id == id);
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return Content("Referans bulunamadı!");
                _db.Attach(refToDel);
                _db.DeleteObject(refToDel);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

I am getting error in _db.Attach() that is:An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. Why is this happenning?

Comment: You are trying to attach an object, that is already attached to. Remove the attach and it may delete your object.

Comment: No. Unfortunatelly that does not work. I tried. It says you have to attach before you delete an object.

Comment: I figure out the problem. var cont = new PhotoGalleryDBEntities4() here is the cont is local I have to use that. But I was using _db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link for how someone else got rid of their "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker." problem.  I hope this helps.

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620084/how-to-get-rid-off-an-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-o)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public ActionResult DeleteItem(int id)
    {
        using (var cont = new PhotoGalleryDBEntities4())
        {
            var refToDel = cont.Referanslars.First(x => x.Id == id);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return Content("Referans bulunamadı!");
            cont.DeleteObject(refToDel);
            cont.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
        return View();
    }
```