# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework

I am getting the following error while trying to update an entity,
'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker'
The code runs as,

```
        dbUsers.Users.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
        dbUsers.Users.Attach(user);
        dbUsers.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
        dbUsers.SaveChanges();
```

Please help me to get rid of it.

Comment: Take a look into this post, may be it can halp you.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620084/how-to-get-rid-off-an-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-o

Comment: User is an object entity to be added. I found a solution, before attaching the entity should be detached. Please reply, if there is better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use same Context**(dbUsers)** any where better to use context**(dbUsers)** as singleton instance.

This will Ensure a class has only one instance and provide a global point of access to it

Check this: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternSingleton.aspx#_self1