# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker?

Tags: entity-framework

```
   Private WorkOrderServicesController As New WorkOrderServicesController

Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

            Dim _WorkOrderServices As New WorkOrderServices
            _WorkOrderServices.Quantity = 1
            _WorkOrderServices.ServiceID = 1
            _WorkOrderServices.UnitCost = 10
            _WorkOrderServices.CreatedBy = StateManager.UserID
            _WorkOrderServices.CreatedDate = Now

             lstWorkOrderServices.Add(_WorkOrderServices)

            grdServices_Fill()

    End Sub
Protected Sub grdServices_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdServices.RowCommand
    If (e.CommandName.Equals("Delete")) Then
        Dim ServiceID = e.CommandArgument
        Dim _WorkOrderService = lstWorkOrderServices.Where(Function(os) os.ServiceID = ServiceID).SingleOrDefault


        If Not _WorkOrderService Is Nothing Then
            If _WorkOrderService.iWOServicesID > 0 Then
                With _WorkOrderService
                    .Deleted = True
                    .DeletedBy = StateManager.UserID
                    .DeletedDate = Now
                End With

                WorkOrderServicesController.UpdateWorkOrderService(_WorkOrderService)
            Else
                lstWorkOrderServices.Remove(_WorkOrderService)
            End If

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Once I pass the EntityObject through UI to DAL and try to Update an Entity, face with an error "entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of"
**** MyDAL.DLL ****

```
Public Class WorkOrderServicesDAL
    Private _context As LAITEntities

    Public Sub New()
        _context = New LAITEntities
    End Sub

    Function UpdateWorkOrderService(ByVal vWorkOrderService As WorkOrderServices) As Boolean
        Try
            'An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
            _context.WorkOrderServices.Attach(vWorkOrderService)
            _context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(vWorkOrderService, EntityState.Modified)
            _context.SaveChanges()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get rid off "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620084/how-to-get-rid-off-an-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-o)

Answer (score 4):

You are probably creating an `ObjectContext` in your DAL, passing the returned object into your UI (at which point the `ObjectContext` you used to retrieve the object with goes out of scope), and then passing the object back into your DAL where you create **another** `ObjectContext` and try to save your changes with this new context.

You can't do this; you either need to keep the original context around, and re-use it (maybe through an instance member on your object) to save the changes back, or you need to Detach the object from the first context instance and re-attach it to the new context.  See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) for details on attaching and detatching.

Comment: I've tried to detach the object " _context.Detach(vWorkOrderService)" but the error occures "The object cannot be detached because it is not attached to the ObjectStateManager."

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code which returns the objects?

Comment: I initialize the class through the line of code as follows "Private WorkOrderServicesController As New WorkOrderServicesController" and do the select and update, not having different instances of the class for select and update so i don't think I have tow ObjectContexts.

Comment: yes sure hold on, but the question is even I tried to detach the object, but it gives me the error. It menas the object is not attached to the ObjectStateManager.

Comment: Do you have proxy creation enabled?

Comment: I use POCO Entities, but the MyBase.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled is False